# PrimeReact Select Item is empty after loading data from API

Tags: reactjs, fetch, jsx, use-effect, primereact

My Functional component is as follows:

```
const Scratch = () => {

 const [isLoaded, setIsLoaded] = useState(false);
 const colorSelectItems=[];
 const [selectedColor, setSelectedColor] = useState("fffff");

 useEffect(() => {
    fetch(
           `http://localhost:8765/fetchData?userId=1`
         )
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
       createDropDown(data));
       setIsLoaded(true);
      });
  }, []);

 const createDropDown= (data) => {
    data.map((color) => {
      colorSelectItems.push({
        label: color.colorName,
        value: color.hexValue,
      });
    });

 return (
     <div className="commonMargin">
         {!isLoaded&& <p>Loading..</p>}
         {isLoaded&& (
           <Dropdown
            value={selectedColor}
            optionLabel="label"
            options={colorSelectItems}
            onChange={(e) => setSelectedColor(e.target.value);}
           />
          )}
     </div>
  );
};

export default Scratch;
```

The problem is, it is displaying **Loading...** until the API call is complete, and it is rendering DropDown after that. But even after the completion of API call, the DropDown is still empty!

What am I missing here?

PS: This DropDown works perfectly if I replace fetching data from API to fetching data from local json file

Comment: You need to set the state in order to re-render the component.

Comment: @YashJoshi           I tried `useState([])` for the colorSelectItems. But it is rendering `bound dispatchAction` as one of the select item

Comment: Can you create a CodeSandbox app, to replicate the issue. Just go to https://react.new  to create the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this .In case any problem plz reply

```
const Scratch = () => {

 const [isLoaded, setIsLoaded] = useState(false);
 const colorSelectItems=[];
 const [selectedColor, setSelectedColor] = useState("fffff");

 useEffect(() => {
    fetch(
           `http://localhost:8765/fetchData?userId=1`
         )
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
       var temp=data?.map((item)=>({label: item?.colorName,
        value: item?.hexValue }));
       colorSelectItems=temp;
       setIsLoaded(true);
      });
  }, []);
     
 return (
     <div className="commonMargin">
         {!isLoaded&& <p>Loading..</p>}
         {isLoaded&& (
           <Dropdown
            value={selectedColor}
            optionLabel="label"
            options={colorSelectItems}
            onChange={(e) => setSelectedColor(e.target.value);}
           />
          )}
     </div>
  );
};

export default Scratch;
```

Comment: Yeah, I had solved the issue in the similar way; with one change. `const [colorSelectItems,setColorSelectItems]=useState([]);` and then instead of  `colorSelectItems=temp;` ,I used `setColorSelectItems(temp)` .

Comment: @Harihara_K ok bro, thanks for the reply and support